# how to place a result from a room database query (Int) into a text view

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-room

This, I thought to have been easy but it is beating me up badly. I have followed several similar responses here but none seem to help in my case.
I have a Room db with a single table; a DAO, a ViewModel, a home screen, and I am using jetpack compose.

To summarize, there is a query that requests a count of items with a (Boolean)field in a certain state (1 or true). The query reurns an integer.

```
// <Test> Number of items for the above query
@Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM grocery_table WHERE checkToAdd = 1")
fun getShoppingItems(): Flow<Int>
```

then there is the vieModel code; this code is within a 'when':

```
is GroceriesEvent.GetShoppingItems -> {
   dao.getShoppingItems()
 Log.d("WALRUS", "The total checked items is: ${GroceriesState.ShoppingItems}")
        }
```

then in my composable, I try to include a text item in the topappbar like this:

```
CenterAlignedTopAppBar(
    title = {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ){
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.groceries),
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.size(60.dp)
            )
            Text(text =  stringResource(R.string.app_name),
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.displayMedium
            )
            Text(text = GroceriesEvent.GetShoppingItems.toString()
            )
        }
    },
    modifier = Modifier
)
```

I have made changes to this since I first asked the question, however I still don't get the result I need. There are no warnings or errors of any kind; however it aborts at start.
More changes to this question as of 1-8-24

Any help to point me in the right direction would be very much appreciated.
Thanks in advance,
Ray.

Comment: Your `getShoppingItems` type is `Int?` in ViewModel and you set it in textview you have to chek first not-null and then convert `Int` to `String`

Comment: I tried the '.toString()' but no diffference.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a result as a Flow

```
 @Query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM grocery_table WHERE checkToAdd = 1")
 fun getShoppingItems(): Flow<Int>
```

and collect in your ViewModel and then collect flow as a state in your composable.

Comment: that is how I started; I have it in the viewModel as: is GroceriesEvent.GetShoppingItems -> {
                _state.update { it.copy(
                    getShoppingItems = it.getShoppingItems
                )}
            }, but then I'm not sure how to add it to the composable.

Comment: so I chnaged the Viewmodel to: is GroceriesEvent.GetShoppingItems -> {
                viewModelScope.launch {
                    dao.getShoppingItems()
                }
            }, but I still can't get the result in the composable....

Comment: You can collect data by using val data by viewModel.GetShoppingItems.collectAsState() in your composable

Comment: thank you for input buddy; however I couldn't do that. I got a lot of red. Please see how I modified my code. Now there is no compilation error, but no result either.

Comment: check my GitHub repo https://github.com/KaushalVasava/Tasks or message me on LinkedIn https://www.linkedin.com/in/kaushal-vasava/